# How do I make my firebase database public

Tags: firebase

I have a database in firebase and I want to make it public like https://publicdata-transit.firebaseio.com/sf-muni
What I see here they have a prefix "pulicdata", How do I get it?

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish by "making it public"?

Comment: To look at it in the browser without authentication

Comment: Ah, you want the *dashboard* to be publicly available? That's a setting that's only available for apps managed by Firebase themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This won't do any formatting (you can make it pretty if you want), but this will take your snapshot and just put it up on the screen for anyone to see as long as you have your settings for read as true.

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id='displaySnapshotDiv'></div>
        <script>
          var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://MY-FIREBASE-NAME-GOES-HERE.firebaseio.com/');
          myDataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
            displaySnapshot(snapshot.val());
          });
          function displaySnapshot(snapshot) {
            $('<div/>').text(JSON.stringify(snapshot)).appendTo($('#displaySnapshotDiv'));
            $('#displaySnapshotDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#displaySnapshotDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
          };
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

If you want it to be a little more readable, you could do something like:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <html>
      <head>
        <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id='displaySnapshotDiv'></div>
        <script>
          var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://MY-FIREBASE-NAME-GOES-HERE.firebaseio.com/');
      myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        displaySnapshotNeatly(snapshot.val());
      });
      function displaySnapshotNeatly(snapshot) {
        $('<div/>').text(JSON.stringify(snapshot)).appendTo($('#displaySnapshotDiv'));
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the second one working in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lukeschlangen/rzfn45pz/

And here is the second one with your firebase data (please tell me the security settings for writing are set to something other than true?): https://jsfiddle.net/lukeschlangen/rzfn45pz/2/

It seems like you might want to do some formatting, but this is displaying all of the data.

Comment: It doesn't help. I need to see a page line this: https://publicdata-transit.firebaseio.com/sf-muni

Comment: Then I think it already works? If you open it in an incognito window (as if you weren't logged into firebase and you were just a normal internet user), it shows the data right there? Is there something more you need?

Comment: Thanks for the answers today @LukeSchlangen.

Comment: @Meir: I already said in a comment that this feature is only available to apps managed by Firebase themselves. So Luke's approach of building a page that displays your data is going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

A publicly accessible read-only dashboard, like the one you're referring to, is only available for apps managed by Firebase themselves. You cannot enable it on your own applications.

Comment: He is talking about database, not dashboard.

Comment: OP is referring to a public-data example, which used to be our public readable databases (which you can do with you Firebase security rules) and a public dashboard (see the second comment to the question). That is a setting that was never available to user-created projects.

Answer (score 1):

The data can be available public if you change your database rules to true or use the auth token for authentication. But since you do not want to authenticate access, all you simply need to do is Make you access rules public

for more information check out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3LqS.png)